# Is an instance really created after A a = new A()?

Tags: java, static

```
public class Tmp {
    public static void main(String[] s) {
        //new Tmp(); //comment 1
    }
    A a = new A(1); //comment 2
}

class A {
    A(int i) {
        System.out.println("value in A: " + i);
    }
}
```

I assumed the object `a` was created after the line with *comment 2* was executed. But nothing was printed. Only after enabling the line with *comment 1*, "value in A: 1" is printed. Then I am confused that when the object is really created? In contrast, `static A a = new A(1);` will print "value in A: 1" even with the line with *comment 1* disabled.

Can anyone explain the mechnism behind this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`A a` is a field of the enclosing class.

(non static) fields get initialized when you instantiate an object of that class. Your `a` field is thus *"filled"* only when a `new Tmp()` takes place.

That is all there is to this.